# PostgreSQL Select combine 2 WITH query

Tags: postgresql

I made a select using the WITH query something like this:

```
WITH test AS (select id, sum(value) as value from test group by id)
SELECT name, t.value from names JOIN test t ON (t.id = names.id)
```

But I need to use 2 WITH queries, is there any way to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH
    name1 AS (SELECT ...),
    name2 AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT ...
```